# why is conntrackd-stats.log so huge?

Tags: networking, logging

I was poking around in my /var/log directory, and I noticed that the conntrackd-stats.log file is 150Mb, and getting a new entry every second.  The logs look like this.  Am I unwittingly hosting something nasty?

```
Sat Nov 12 19:07:07 2016        tcp      6 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=54208 dport=4101 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=4101 dport=54208 
Sat Nov 12 19:07:07 2016        tcp      6 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=54212 dport=4101 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=4101 dport=54212 
Sat Nov 12 19:07:08 2016        tcp      6 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=54216 dport=4101 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=4101 dport=54216 
Sat Nov 12 19:07:08 2016        tcp      6 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=54220 dport=4101 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=4101 dport=54220 
Sat Nov 12 19:07:08 2016        tcp      6 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=54224 dport=4101 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=4101 dport=54224
```